# List<String> to Map<String,String> with stream, with String splitting

Tags: java, string, list, split, java-stream

I have List with Strings:

```
List<String> cookiesUpdate = Arrays.asList("A=2" , "B=3");
```

I want to convert it to Map:

```
{
  "A": "2",
  "B": "3"
}
```

Code:

```
Map<String, String> cookies = cookiesUpdate.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, String::toString));
```

How to write those splitters above? If compiler thinks key String is Object.

```
.split("=")[0];
.split("=")[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Split should be done by `"="` (or `"\\s*=\\s"` to exclude whitespaces around `=`)

*Update* Also it is better to provide `limit` argument to `String::split` to split at the first occurrence of `"="`, thanks @AndrewF for suggestion!

2. Fix `toMap` collector to use the first element of the array as key and the last as the value; a merge function may be needed if several namesake cookies are possible

```java
Map<String, String> map = cookies.stream()
    .map(ck -> ck.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2)) // Stream<String[]>
    .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // ignore invalid cookies
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1], (v1, v2) -> v1));
```

If there are multiple cookies with the same name, it may be worth to collect them into `Set<String>` thus keeping all unique values.  For this, `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> map2 = cookies.stream()
    .map(ck -> ck.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2)) // Stream<String[]>
    .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // ignore invalid cookies
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        arr -> arr[0], 
        Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toSet())
    ));
```

Comment: Consider `String.split( /* ... */ , 2)` so that any equals signs in the _value_ will not result in an array with _length > 2_ and truncated value in the final result.

Comment: `String.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2)` will result in a compilation error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method split(String, int) from the type String`.   And you don't need `, (v1, v2) -> v1`.

Comment: @saka1029, you're right, it should be `ck.split`, I fixed that.  The merge function _may be_ needed to handle possible duplicates of cookie names to prevent failing after `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key a (attempted merging values b and c)` if the test data are: `List<String> cookies = Arrays.asList("a=b", "a=c", "p=qqq");`